# How to use ApplicationDbContext outside the controller in Asp .Net 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I am using Asp .Net 5 to create a WebApi and I am trying to put all database operations in a separate class, the problem is I can't Use ApplicationDbContext by initiating a new object because it takes an argument in the constructor.

my context :

```
 public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
```

controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AttributesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetAllAttributes")]
        public async Task<AllAttributes> GetAllAttributes()
        {
            return await new Services.AttributeService().GetAll();
        }
    }
```

service :

```
public class AttributeService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db ;
        public async Task<AllAttributes> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                var dbAttributes = await _db.Attributes.Where(attr=> (bool)attr.IsActive && !(bool)attr.IsDeleted && !(bool)attr.IsTrashed).ToListAsync();
                if (dbAttributes.Count>0)
                {
                    return new AllAttributes
                    {
                        Attributes = dbAttributes,
                        Message = new ResponseMessage
                        {
                            Message = "Success",
                            Code = 200
                        }
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new AllAttributes
                    {
                        Message = new ResponseMessage
                        {
                            Message = "Empty",
                            Code = 410
                        }
                    };
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new AllAttributes
                {
                    Message = new ResponseMessage
                    {
                        Message = ex.Message,
                        Code = 500
                    }
                };
            }
        }}
```

so when I call it like this I got `NullReference` Exception.

Comment: Register either AttributeService and DbContext to DI container and use injection to reach 
them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Injecting DbContext into service layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058142/injecting-dbcontext-into-service-layer)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt 
I did all this, my problem was in the Controller constructor to pass the service 
`public AttributesController(AttributeService _attributeService)
        {
            attributeService = _attributeService;
        }`
which is not mentioned there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `AttributeService` to the DI container.  You can do this inside `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<AttributeService>();
```

Then you can inject the context in the constructor of `AttributeService`:

```
public class AttributeService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db ;

    public AttributeService(ApplicationDbContext db) 
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Yes it's working now using DI and inject the service to the DI container

`[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AttributesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AttributeService attributeService;
        public AttributesController(AttributeService _attributeService)
        {
            attributeService = _attributeService;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetAllAttributes")]
        public async Task<AllAttributes> GetAllAttributes()
        {
            return await attributeService.GetAll();
        }
    }`